# Confluent Kafka docker containers will not start

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to install and run confluent Kafka on Mac using the Docker image. I follow the instructions here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html

But I cannot get all my containers to run, keep getting ' Exit ' status. What did I do wrong.

```
(base) Dev-iMac:docker-confluent dev1$ docker-compose up -d
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

zookeeper is up-to-date
Starting broker ... done
Starting schema-registry ... done
Starting connect         ... done
Starting rest-proxy      ... done
Starting ksqldb-server   ... done
control-center is up-to-date
ksqldb-cli is up-to-date
Starting ksql-datagen    ... done
(base) Dev-iMac:docker-confluent dev1$ docker-compose ps
     Name                  Command            State              Ports          
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
broker            /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up       0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp,  
                                                       0.0.0.0:9101->9101/tcp   
connect           /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up       0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp,  
                                                       9092/tcp                 
control-center    /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up       0.0.0.0:9021->9021/tcp   
ksql-datagen      bash -c echo Waiting for    Exit 1                            
                  K ...                                                         
ksqldb-cli        /bin/sh                     Up                                
ksqldb-server     /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up       0.0.0.0:8088->8088/tcp   
rest-proxy        /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 1                            
schema-registry   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 1                            
zookeeper         /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up       0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp,  
                                                       2888/tcp, 3888/tcp
```

Comment: (1) Did you allocate enough memory to Docker? (2) what's the error you see for the containers that have stopped in `docker logs <container-name>` ?

Comment: Did you read the prereq section? _Docker memory is allocated minimally at 6 GB. When using Docker Desktop for Mac, the default Docker memory allocation is 2 GB._ If you don't need every single service (such as really only needing Kafka}, then start removing things

Comment: My docker memory preferences are set at 6 GB, so no issue there.

Comment: Were you able to figure something out?